# Update panel with timer keeps scrolling page automatically

Tags: asp.net, timer, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using 3 timer of 1000ms , 500ms , 3000ms with multiple update panel in a single page but when running it into live project the page automatically keeps scrolling up and down.Running it in localhost also has same problem with minor effect. Can any one explain why and how to solve?

I have also put

```
    <pages smartNavigation="true" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"></pages>
```

in my webconfig file

here is my code

```
    <div class="card-heading">
        <h2 class="teamProfile100-form-title">Auction Arena</h2>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSpectatorsCount" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="tmSpectatorsCount" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="tmSpectatorsCount_Tick"></asp:Timer>
                <div style="float: right; background-color: white" class="oval">
                    <p style="padding-top: 5px">
                        <i class="far fa-eye"></i>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSpectatorsCount" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Font-Italic="true" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmSpectatorsCount" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upError" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="name"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Timer ID="tm1000ms" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="tm1000ms_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Timer ID="tm3000ms" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="tm3000ms_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Timer ID="tm500ms" runat="server" Interval="500" OnTick="tm500ms_Tick"></asp:Timer>

    <%-- Display Timer for Auction --%>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>

        <div class="col-md-2" style="float: left">
            <div class="squareBOX" id="timerblock">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTimerAuction" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:Timer ID="timerAuction" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timerAuction_Tick"></asp:Timer>--%>
                        <i class="far fa-stopwatch"></i>
                        <asp:Literal ID="litTimer" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm1000ms" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row" style="padding-top: 5px">

        <%-- Display Total Team budget --%>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top: 101px">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTeamBudget" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="rectangleBOXRigth" id="divTeamBudget" runat="server">
                        <p style="padding-top: 10px">
                            Budget LEFT
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTeamBudget" runat="server" CssClass="budgetStyle" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Label>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPlayerCard" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <%--<asp:Timer ID="tmPlayerCard" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="tmPlayerCard_Tick"></asp:Timer>--%>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rpAuctionPlayer" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpAuctionPlayer_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="cardM horizontal">
                                <div class="cardM-image">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgPlayerProfilePic" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("PlayerProfilePic") %>' CssClass="img-fluid rounded" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPlayerID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("PlayerID") %>' EnableViewState="false" />
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-weight: bold">
                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:Literal ID="litPlayerName" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text="Name"></asp:Literal>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPlayerName" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("PlayerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        .......</table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardM-action">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlBIO" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="Bio()">Bio</asp:HyperLink>
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlBAT" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="Bat()">Bat</asp:HyperLink>
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlBOWL" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="Bowl()">Bowl</asp:HyperLink>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm3000ms" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top: 27px">
            <div class="rectangleBOXLeft">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upBiddingTeam" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:Timer ID="tmBiddingCount" runat="server" Interval="500" OnTick="tmBiddingCount_Tick"></asp:Timer>--%>
                        <p style="text-align: center">
                            Total team count :
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBiddingTeamCount" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                        </p>

                        <asp:Repeater ID="rpBiddingTeam" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgTeamLogo" Height="36px" Width="36px" runat="server" CssClass="img-fluid rounded-circle" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("TeamLogo") %>' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <p>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblTeamName" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%#Eval("TeamName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <p>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblTeamBidAmount" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%#Eval("CurrentBidAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm500ms" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <%-- Display Bid Amount --%>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center">

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCurrentBid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <%--<asp:Timer ID="tmCurrentBid" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="tmCurrentBid_Tick"></asp:Timer>--%>
                    <div class="squareBOX" style="width: 135px; background-color: white; padding: 3px 2px">
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBidName" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <i class="fal fa-rupee-sign"></i>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentBid" runat="server" Font-Names="Poppins-Regular" Font-Size="19px" EnableViewState="true">
                        </asp:Label>

                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm1000ms" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>

        <%-- Display Team Player List --%>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top: 10px">
            <div class="rectangleBOXLeft" id="divTeamPlayerList" runat="server">

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTeamList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:Timer ID="tmTeamList" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="tmTeamList_Tick"></asp:Timer>--%>
                        <div class="HeaderBottom">
                            <div style="border-right: 3px solid #d9d9d9; display: inline-block">
                                <p style="padding-right: 7px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTeamNameHeader" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: inline-block">
                                <p style="padding-left: 5px">
                                    Players &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTotalPlayerCount" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;/&nbsp;25
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnTeamInfoList" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="130px">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rpTeamInfoList" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="form-row" style="text-align: center">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgPlayerLogoList" Height="36px" Width="36px" runat="server" CssClass="img-fluid rounded-circle" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("PlayerProfilePic") %>' />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <p>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPlayerNameList" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%#Eval("PlayerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <p>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPlayerBidAmountList" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%#Eval("PlayerSoldPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <div class="FooterBottom">
                            <div style="border-right: 3px solid #d9d9d9; display: inline-block">
                                <r style="padding-right: 5px">
                                Overseas &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTotalOverseas" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;/&nbsp;8
                            </r>
                            </div>
                            <div style="float: right; display: inline-block; padding-right: 10px">
                                <r style="padding-right: 5px">
                                    Indian &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTotalIndian" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;/&nbsp;17
                                </r>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </ContentTemplate>

                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tm3000ms" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

just add this script to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);

    function beginRequest() {
        prm._scrollPosition = null;
    }
</script>
```